# Find $n$ such that the polynomial function $1+X+X^2$ divides $(1+X^4)^n-X^n$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Find $n$ such that the polynomial function $1+X+X^2$ divides $P_n = (1+X^4)^n-X^n$.

What I've written is
$$
\left(1+X^4\right)^n - X^n = \left(1+X+X^2\right)Q\left(X\right) + R\left(X\right)
$$
where $R\left(X\right) = aX+b$. Finding $a$ and $b$ as function of $n$ 'd lead me to the result by putting $a=b=0$.

What I've tried is to evaluate the equation in $e^{2i\pi/3}$ and  $e^{-2i\pi/3}$ which are the roots of $1+X+X^2$ then
$$
P_n\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right) = R\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right) \text{ and also }P_n\left(e^{-2i\pi/3}\right) = R\left(e^{-2i\pi/3}\right)
$$
However my problem 'd be to simplify as far as I can $P_n\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right)$ :
$$P_n\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right) = \left(1+e^{8 i \pi/3}\right)^n-\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right)^n=\left(1+e^{2 i \pi/3}\right)^n-\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+e^{2i\pi/3}\right)^{n-k}\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right)^k
$$
Then, yes I can make the sum of a geometrical sequence terms appear, but it looks still not friendly to manipulate. Is there a better way to go to solve the problem ? I think the result is $n$ being a multiple of $6$

Thanks for the help

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3391593/11619) manipulations of third roots of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Your link is an *exact* dupe of the link I posted a minute prior on your answer. These dupes (and minor variants) are everywhere...

Comment: Reposting the comment so that dust can settle. Evaluation at $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ is a good idea (+1). We have $\omega^3=1$ and
$$1+\omega+\omega^2=0 \implies 1+\omega=-\omega^2.$$
Additionally you need to use $\omega^4=\omega$. With these hints you can surely evaluate $(1+X^4)^n-X^n$ at $X=\omega$, and find out when it simplifies to zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Probably the "n mins ago" time was out of sync before page refresh. I don't see any need to waste further time. The key ideas are already in [said answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217567/242) (and its link).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Your tip just made it so easy, thanks for that, appreciated it

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry about needing to close this as a duplicate. I was on a fence about it, but another user agreed. FWIW the upvote is mine.